# Object becomes null when used on a void method

Tags: c#

I have a void method.`versionControl` is already initialized beforehand but I still get a null exception on `workspace` and `versionControl` on this method.

```
//populate a comboBox with the available workspaces
public IEnumerable<string> GetWorkspace(string path)
{
        versionControl = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
        Workspace[] retVal = versionControl.QueryWorkspaces(null, versionControl.AuthorizedUser, Environment.MachineName );
        foreach (Workspace w in retVal)
        {
            yield return w.Name;
        }
}

//gets the selected workspace in the combo box from the MainForm()
    public void MapWorkspace(string selectedWorkspace)
    {
        var workspace = versionControl.GetWorkspace(selectedWorkspace, versionControl.AuthorizedUser);
    }
```

Comment: Where is `versionControl` defined? Please show all relevant code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this method is using deferred execution([`yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0.aspx)) `versionControl` is instantiated only if the *query* is executed because it's enumerated, for example by using `ToList` or `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var query = GetWorkspace(path);        // versionControl  is null
var workSpace = query.FirstOrDefault() // now versionControl is instantiated
```

I would not initialize fields in methods  that are using deferred execution for this reason.

**Edit**: here's  a demonstration of this behaviour: http://ideone.com/CVwzZZ

Comment: Thanks. Should I change line/s of code with that? I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with query.

Comment: @user2379805: So you need to access `versionControl` from multiple methods in your class. Then the constructor of this class would be a good place to initialize `versionControl`. Or you yould make it a property which checks first if it's initialized. If not `tpc.GetService` is called. However, i have not enough background informations to give you better sugestions. Maybe you want to ask a different question for this.

Comment: I instantiate versionControl as `private VersionControlServer versionControl;`

Comment: That is a declaration, the object is still `null`. It is initialized where you assign something. Initialization normally occurs in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I get that. Anyway, I forgot to mention that in `GetWorkspace`, a list of workspace is returned to the MainForm. While in `MapWorkspace`, it gets the workspace selected from the MainForm and map that selected workspace.

Comment: @user2379805: Why have you unaccept the answer, do you need still  support?

Comment: I sort of struggle before so I double checked my code with your solution. Anyway, thanks. :)